# Can't send image to server with Retrofit

Tags: php, android, retrofit

I'm using `Retrofit` library to upload file to php server but an `Unknow error` occurs.

Here my Android code :

**Retrofit Service :**

```
@Multipart
@POST("/upload_image.php")
public void uploadImage(@Part("file") TypedFile file, @Query("id_client") long id_client, @Query("id_obj") long id_obj, Callback<Boolean> callback);
```

**Upload code :**

```
public void uploadImage(String imagePath, long, clientId, Obj obj, Callback<Boolean> callback) {
    TypedFile typedFile = new TypedFile("application/octet-stream", new File(imagePath));
    mService.uploadImage(typedFile, clientId, obj.getId(), callback);
}
```

**Php code :**

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  $destination)){
   echo ("Stored     in".$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/Uploader/UploadedFiles/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
} else {
$html_body = '<h1>File upload error!</h1>';
switch ($_FILES[0]['error']) {
case 1:
   $html_body .= 'The file is bigger than this PHP installation allows';
   break;
case 2:
   $html_body .= 'The file is bigger than this form allows';
   break;
case 3:
  $html_body .= 'Only part of the file was uploaded';
  break;
case 4:
   $html_body .= 'No file was uploaded';
   break;
default:
   $html_body .= 'unknown errror';
} 
echo ($html_body);
}
```

On image upload, server returns : "unknown errror".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your switch defaults to unknown error, and UPLOAD_ERR_OK has value of zero

therefore you should check if `$_FILES['image']['error']` has value of 0 and if so, skip this error handling

Actually it looks like the move_uploaded_file fails, but its hard to tell not knowing what `$destination` variable points to

But you should check if $destination is a valid file to write to and the process has permissions to write there

Also as a good coding practice you shouldn't use magic values such as 1, 2, 3.. use constants instead! `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`, `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`..

..

Also looks like you've also tried it with form and it works

You should check if the `TypedFile` in the device points to an *existing file*

I am using retrofit in exactly the same way and its working **perfectly**

If all that fails, I would try monitoring the traffic using a HTTP traffic monitoring proxy such as *Charles*

and see if the file gets actually sent

But I would say that the typedfile doesn't point to a valid file

Comment: I've test with an html form, and it works. With Retrofit, it doesn't works

Comment: I've enabled logs for retrofit, and I can see that the file is sent. file.exists() return true...

Comment: On the switch statement you're using $_FILES[0] and other places $_FILES['file'], are they nesseccery the same file? If the form works, you should compare the requests of the application and of the web page and see whats different and make modifications based on the differences

Comment: All right, I'll try. Could you show me your code please ?

Comment: All right, I run the test and no error occurs, but no image on the server !

Comment: Its pretty hard to say from the facts given.. Does the image get saved when you use form? I suspect not

Comment: It works with the form, I can upload the image, but not via Retrofit... Is "application/octet-stream" the problem ?